# How to lead in postgresql?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

I have a table in the below format

```
id       task_start_time            task_end_time
__       _______________            _____________
1       2017-03-21 00:09:10     2017-03-21 00:12:18
1       2017-03-21 00:12:19     2017-03-21 00:12:56
1       2017-03-21 00:12:57     2017-03-21 00:13:10
2       2017-03-21 10:09:10     2017-03-21 10:25:34
2       2017-03-21 10:25:34     2017-03-21 11:09:10
2       2017-03-21 11:09:10     2017-03-21 11:21:39
3       2017-03-21 12:09:10     2017-03-21 12:19:19
3       2017-03-21 12:19:19     2017-03-21 12:29:19
3       2017-03-21 12:29:10     2017-03-21 12:39:10
```

from this table I need to update the table by adding another column which is the previous row of the particular id's task_end_time which is the task_end_time of the id.

```
id       task_start_time            task_end_time        previous_task_end_time

__       _______________            _____________       ______________________
1       2017-03-21 00:09:10     2017-03-21 00:12:18             NA
1       2017-03-21 00:12:19     2017-03-21 00:12:56             2017-03-21 00:12:18 
1       2017-03-21 00:12:57     2017-03-21 00:13:10             2017-03-21 00:12:56
2       2017-03-21 10:09:10     2017-03-21 10:25:34             2017-03-21 10:25:34
2       2017-03-21 10:25:34     2017-03-21 11:09:10             2017-03-21 11:09:10
2       2017-03-21 11:09:10     2017-03-21 11:21:39             2017-03-21 11:21:39
3       2017-03-21 12:09:10     2017-03-21 12:19:19             2017-03-21 12:19:19
3       2017-03-21 12:19:19     2017-03-21 12:29:19             2017-03-21 12:29:19
3       2017-03-21 12:29:10     2017-03-21 12:39:10             2017-03-21 12:39:10
```

So can be this done easily in postgresql or should I need to use JAVA to implement this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) `lag`.

```sql
SELECT id, task_start_time, task_end_time
     , LAG(task_end_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY task_end_time) AS previous_task_end_time
  FROM ...
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91641/2) for running example.

```
id  task_start_time         task_end_time           previous_task_end_time
1   2017-03-21 00:09:10     2017-03-21 00:12:18     (null)
1   2017-03-21 00:12:19     2017-03-21 00:12:56     2017-03-21 00:12:18
1   2017-03-21 00:12:57     2017-03-21 00:13:10     2017-03-21 00:12:56
2   2017-03-21 10:09:10     2017-03-21 10:25:34     (null)
2   2017-03-21 10:25:34     2017-03-21 11:09:10     2017-03-21 10:25:34
2   2017-03-21 11:09:10     2017-03-21 11:21:39     2017-03-21 11:09:10
3   2017-03-21 12:09:10     2017-03-21 12:19:19     (null)
3   2017-03-21 12:19:19     2017-03-21 12:29:19     2017-03-21 12:19:19
3   2017-03-21 12:29:10     2017-03-21 12:39:10     2017-03-21 12:29:19
```

Comment: Thanks a lot a quick question does this works for update by changing the sql into `update ... set  previous_task_end_time=LAG(task_end_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY task_end_time)`

Comment: No. For update try `UPDATE mytable a SET previous_task_end_time = ( SELECT MAX(b.task_end_time) FROM mytable b WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.task_end_time < a.task_end_time )`